# AsyncStorage not resolving or rejecting

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get an item from async storage.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount')
    AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
      .then(storage => console.log('then', storage))
      .catch(err => console.log('catch', err))
}
```

Also trying this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount')
    AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY, (err, data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      console.log('err', err)
    });
 }
```

But no matter how I do it, the debugger is outputting only the `componentDidMount` log and I'm not getting results at all.

Any idea what's wrong here?

**EDIT:** I'm running the app through expo

Comment: Same situation here. Could you manage to find any results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with expo. After restarting expo completely the same code I originally posted worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
async componentDidMount(){  
  await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)  
    .then( (value) =>{  
       console.warn(value);  
    }  
 );  
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I've tried using `async/await` instead of normal `Promise` handlings but didn´t work

Comment: can you please give me your code ? i'll try on my system.

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like it was some issue with expo. The first example I sent works now after restarting everything.

Comment: Completely restarting Expo did it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with android, and I could only solve it bundling.

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`.

I added this command in the scripts in package.json.

Answer (score -2):

AsyncStorage is an asynchronous function. It means that id you 'd like to use it in a function, it have to be asynchronous. The way to make it asynchronous is putting async keyword before the name of the function.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount')
    AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
      .then(storage => console.log('then', storage))
      .catch(err => console.log('catch', err))
}
```

This is how it should be. Greetings

Comment: There is no need to use `async` when handling promises with `then` function

Comment: There is a known bug that it does not resolve arbitrarily: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16905