# AsyncStorage undefined check

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

How do I determine if asyncstorage is in

Error rejection

```
if (await AsyncStorage.getItem("id") == undefined){
    alert("yes");
}
```

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251830/asyncstorage-not-resolving-or-rejecting

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check for a failed getItem call (happened to me on simulator, had to reinstall the app for it to work again), you can try to wrap your code in a try-catch, this way :

```
try {
    if (await AsyncStorage.getItem("id") == undefined){
        alert("item not found ");
}
} catch(error) {
    console.log("getItem function failed", error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way of achieving this would be:

```
const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem("id")   // Get the item reference of ID if exists

if (id) {
   // Do what you want if ID is actually there
} else {
   // Do what you want if ID is not there
}
```